# I'm gonna move my SSD from my laptop to a desktop computer. Do I need to reinstall the OS?

Tags: laptop, .desktop, reinstall, motherboard

I have read many similar questions and they all said I wouldn't need to reinstall the OS, but I just want to be sure, as none of them mentioned switching from a laptop to a desktop computer.

Comment: If your `/etc/fstab` specifies partitions with the `UUID=` syntax, probably.

Comment: It's best practice to do a fresh installation if you are making a significant hardware change.

Comment: Laptop vs desktop doesn't matter. In my experience you can cleanly move any linux hard drive between physical or virtual computers, but you quite often have to remove old graphics drivers and install the graphics driver for new location. (Unless you have a situation where say, both onboard cards are maybe a "Geforce 8200"... or maybe both PCs just happen to use the same driver... or maybe you didn't install any graphics drivers at all and you just used the default config). It is worth just trying and seeing what happens... BUT, your question doesn't actually mention anything "linux" at all.